# Export jars from library project in Eclipse

Tags: java, web-services, war, jni4net

I have a Dynamic Web Project with a reference to a library project. When I export the .war file and try to call the method I got:

org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jni4net/Bridge

When I look into my .war file, the jars of the library project were not exported. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project, click 'Properties'. Next select 'Deployment Assembly'. Click the 'Add...' button to add my jar files that you need to be included in the exported war file.